# |VB.NET| Timer not starting if called in separate thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, tcp, timer

I am trying to make a TCP connection client-server and in order to do so i use a timer to make polling of received messages.
Code is following:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Dim TCPServer As Socket
Dim TCPListenerz As TcpListener
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Windows.Forms.Timer

Sub listenthread()
    TCPListenerz = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1000)
    TCPListenerz.Start()
    TCPServer = TCPListenerz.AcceptSocket()
    TCPServer.Blocking = False
    Button2.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Dim listen As New Thread(AddressOf listenthread)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text)
    TCPServer.Send(sendbytes)

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        Dim rcvbytes(TCPServer.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        TCPServer.Receive(rcvbytes)
        TextBox3.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvbytes)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    listen.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that in this way the timer never starts even if the listenthread starts correctly.
More strangely is that if i use the same code of the listenthread in a click event for a button of the main thread the timer will correctly start:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Dim TCPServer As Socket
Dim TCPListenerz As TcpListener
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox2.Text)
    TCPServer.Send(sendbytes)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

TCPListenerz = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1000)
TCPListenerz.Start()
TCPServer = TCPListenerz.AcceptSocket()
TCPServer.Blocking = False
Button2.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen
Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        Dim rcvbytes(TCPServer.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        TCPServer.Receive(rcvbytes)
        TextBox3.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvbytes)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

Any reason why the timer do not start if called in different thread?

Comment: Probably because the windows.forms.timer is a UI object and can only run on the ui thread. Try using System.Timers.Timer instead

Comment: I think I found the problem and you helped me in this:
there is a try block in the timer tick event, and so i could not see that it was generating an error because I was trying to handle a UI object in a seperate thread from the one where it was created, so if I want to keep the code like this I have to add an Invoke statement to manage the situation.